# Get data from remote Orthanc Server to Ohif viewer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, server, viewer, medical-imaging

I have my app which is working on docker.
On local version of app I run my Ohif viewer I am using command yarn run dev:orthanc.
Due to the fact that I want to have data from remote Orhtanc server I changed on package.json file script "dev:orthanc" from 1) to 2) and eveyrthing work correctly. I have images from Orthanc server on my local machine viewer.

1. "dev:orthanc": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development PROXY_TARGET=/dicom-web PROXY_DOMAIN=http://localhost:8042 APP_CONFIG=config/docker_nginx-orthanc.js webpack-dev-server --config .webpack/webpack.pwa.js --watch",
2. "dev:orthanc": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development PROXY_TARGET=/dicom-web PROXY_DOMAIN=http://myRemoteServerIP:8042 APP_CONFIG=config/docker_nginx-orthanc.js webpack-dev-server --config .webpack/webpack.pwa.js --watch",

Now I want to do the same but on GCP instance.
How can I do it?
I tried to change all the urls with localhost to my instance IP but it doesnt work.
I also tried to run ohif viewer on docker-compose container but in my solution it doesnt work.

```
viewer:
    container_name: ohif-viewer
    build:
      context: ./ohif-viewer/Viewers/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/ohif
    volumes:
    - ./config/default.js:/usr/share/nginx/html/config/default.js
    depends_on:
    - comiere-mongo
```

Can someone help me and tell how to run it on production server with images from remote server which IP I have?

Answer (score 0):

Either your Instance needs port 27017 FW rule set or you'd need to add an ingress FW rule for port 27017 at the project [level](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls). Create a permissive FW rule for on the same VPC as the instance, adjust the priority (give higher priority) source 0.0.0.0/0, TCP/UDP and test this out.

> > Ensure that the external IP has not [changed](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#externaladdresses).